# Euler's method proof of the limit formula for $e$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

While using Euler's method for $\frac{dy}{dx}=y$ given $y(0)=1$ I noticed that the approximate solution is $(1+1/s)^{sx}$ where s is the interval size. Plug in one for $x$ and you get:

$$e^{1}=\lim_{s\to\infty}\,(1+1/s)^{s}$$

you get $e$. This *has* to be $e$ because that is that is the solution to the differential equation. Is this a new proof that

$$e=\lim_{s\to\infty}\,(1+1/s)^{s}$$

- List item

Comment: You need an initial condition and a proof that Euler's method approaches that particular solution to that differential equation.

Comment: You know, for me, as $s\to0$, it looks like we have $e=1$.

Comment: Did you meant the limit as $s$ approaches infinity, because $e$ does not equal the limit you gave, which converges to 1. $s$ could perhaps be the number of intervals you have?

Comment: Yes i ment infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define $e$. If you define $e$ as
\begin{align}
e := \lim_{s \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{s} \right)^s
\end{align}
Then (of course) it trivially follows that it is true ($e = e$ end proof).

Although if you define $e$ as the solution to the Initial Value Problem
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y \\
y(0) &= 1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
at the value $x = 1$, or if you define $e$ some other way and *prove* that $e^x$ is the solution to this IVP, and then in addition you prove (or are allowed to assume) that Euler's Method will in fact converge upon the unique solution to the IVP, then yes: what you have written would suffice as another proof that
$$ e = \lim_{s \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{s} \right)^s $$